# IOS. Incorrect Post Script Name and Full Name for a font?

Tags: ios, fonts

I'm trying to dynamically add fonts to the application. Upon registration of a font, such as Chinese, I return an incorrect value. Full Name = "?????????", Post Script Name = "SCFZXFXS". How do I get the original full font name like "书体坊禚效锋行草体"?

```
NSString *resultFontName = nil;
NSString *fullFontName = nil;
NSError *error;
NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlToFont options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];

if(inData) {
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)inData);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
    if (font != NULL)
    {
        CFErrorRef error;
        if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
            NSString *fontName = (__bridge NSString *)CGFontCopyPostScriptName(font);

            UIFont *resultFont = ([UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:26]);
            if (resultFont)
            {
                resultFontName = fontName;
                fullFontName = (__bridge NSString *)CGFontCopyFullName(font);


            }
        }
        else {
            CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
            NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
            CFRelease(errorDescription);

        }
        CFRelease(font);
    }
    CFRelease(provider);
}
```

Comment: run the font through TTX, and have a look at its name table. What platform and encoding is the name table in? because that will tell you how you need to interpret the string before it'll render sensibly